# Force Closes on Opening Activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app where you touch the screen and the basketball moves there. I am almost there except it force closes when you open this mini-app from a list of activities to start. After scanning through several times I could not find anything.

This is my Java Class and after is the Logcat:

```
package com.frostbytedev.addsub;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    OurView v;
    Bitmap ball;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v = new OurView(this);
        setContentView(v);
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bball);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOkay = false;

        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(isItOkay) {
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                c.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 150);
                c.drawBitmap(ball, x-(ball.getWidth()/2), y-(ball.getHeight()/2), null);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        public void pause(){
            isItOkay = false;
            while(true){
                try{
                    t.join();
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void resume() {
            isItOkay = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-09 19:24:35.730: D/libEGL(8218): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
05-09 19:24:35.740: D/libEGL(8218): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
05-09 19:24:35.750: D/libEGL(8218): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
05-09 19:24:35.800: D/OpenGLRenderer(8218): Enabling debug mode 0
05-09 19:24:44.658: D/AndroidRuntime(8218): Shutting down VM
05-09 19:24:44.658: W/dalvikvm(8218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7a930)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at com.frostbytedev.addsub.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:25)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1102)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2751)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3426)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
05-09 19:24:44.668: E/AndroidRuntime(8218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's wrote  `at com.frostbytedev.addsub.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:25)` ?

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to get index [5] of an array that only has length 5, which means that [4] is the highest index item. So you are geting Index OutOfBounds exception. Looks like it is in a different piece of code than what you posted here where it is happening though.